# Perform multiple calculations based on multiple conditions on multiple columns in R

Tags: r, function, data.table, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I working on a dataframe with timeslots, IDs and multiple variables.

```
set.seed(1)
timeslot = c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3),rep(3,3),rep(4,3))
ID = c("A","B","C","D","B","C","C","B","C","A","B","D")
variable1 = c(as.integer(rnorm(12,2)**3)-1)
variable2 = c(as.integer(rnorm(12,4)**2)+1)
df = data.frame(timeslot,ID,variable1,variable2)
```

The dataframe:

```
   timeslot ID variable1 variable2
1         1  A         1        12
2         1  B         9         4
3         1  C         0        27
4         2  D        45        16
5         2  B        11        16
6         2  C         0        25
7         3  C        14        24
8         3  B        19        22
9         3  C        16        25
10        4  A         3        23
11        4  B        42        17
12        4  D        12         5
```

I want to perform some calculations on specific rows. For each row it looks whether that specific ID (A,B,C or D) is present not only in its own timeslot, but also in the previous timeslot. Below is the column added via the following code (Thanks to **code_is_entropy**:

```
df$min1 <- sapply(seq(nrow(df)), function(x)
{
  if(df[x, "timeslot"] == 1){0} else {
    max(df[x, "ID"] %in% df[df$timeslot == df[x,"timeslot"] - 1,"ID"])}
})

   timeslot ID variable1 variable2 min1
1         1  A         1        12    0
2         1  B         9         4    0
3         1  C         0        27    0
4         2  D        45        16    0
5         2  B        11        16    1
6         2  C         0        25    1
7         3  C        14        24    1
8         3  B        19        22    1
9         3  C        16        25    1
10        4  A         3        23    0
11        4  B        42        17    1
12        4  D        12         5    0
```

For these rows calculations should be made. The other rows can have value 0. I want to include several different functions (also 'home-made'). These functions should run over all variables (in reality more than 2).

I succeeded in doing so for the functions sum, max, count &count_not_zero by using this code:

```
sumprev = c()
maxprev = c()
lengthprev = c()
lengthnotzeroprev = c()
j=0
for (j in 1:(length(df$timeslot))){
  if (df[j,"min1"] == 0){sumprev = c(sumprev,0); maxprev = c(maxprev,0); lengthnotzeroprev = c(lengthnotzeroprev,0); lengthprev = c(lengthprev,0)} else {
    sumprev = c(sumprev,(sum(df[which((df[,"timeslot"] == df[j,"timeslot"] | df[,"timeslot"] == (df[j,"timeslot"]-1)) & df[,"ID"]==(df[j,"ID"])),"variable1"])))
    maxprev = c(maxprev,(max(df[which((df[,"timeslot"] == df[j,"timeslot"] | df[,"timeslot"] == (df[j,"timeslot"]-1)) & df[,"ID"]==(df[j,"ID"])),"variable1"])))
    lengthprev = c(lengthprev,(length(df[which((df[,"timeslot"] == df[j,"timeslot"] | df[,"timeslot"] == (df[j,"timeslot"]-1)) & df[,"ID"]==(df[j,"ID"])),"variable1"])))
    lengthnotzeroprev = c(lengthnotzeroprev,(length(df[which((df[,"timeslot"] == df[j,"timeslot"] | df[,"timeslot"] == (df[j,"timeslot"]-1)) & df[,"ID"]==(df[j,"ID"])),"variable1"][df[which((df[,"timeslot"] == df[j,"timeslot"] | df[,"timeslot"] == (df[j,"timeslot"]-1)) & df[,"ID"]==(df[j,"ID"])),"variable1"]])))
    }
}
df = cbind(df,sumprev,maxprev, lengthprev,lengthnotzeroprev)


   timeslot ID variable1 variable2 min1 sumprev maxprev lengthprev lengthnotzeroprev
1         1  A         1        12    0       0       0          0                 0
2         1  B         9         4    0       0       0          0                 0
3         1  C         0        27    0       0       0          0                 0
4         2  D        45        16    0       0       0          0                 0
5         2  B        11        16    1      20      11          2                 2
6         2  C         0        25    1       0       0          2                 0
7         3  C        14        24    1      30      16          3                 2
8         3  B        19        22    1      30      19          2                 2
9         3  C        16        25    1      30      16          3                 2
10        4  A         3        23    0       0       0          0                 0
11        4  B        42        17    1      61      42          2                 2
12        4  D        12         5    0       0       0          0                 0
```

This is rather crude and I can't figure out how to do this easily for multiple functions and for more than 1 variable.

I struggled with data.table package to get something but I can't seem to work out how to get it done.

*Sorry for anything I do wrong, I am new to R and StackOverflow and not a native speaker.*

Comment: You should better describe how the new columns should be calculated. For example for `ID == 'B'`, `sumprev` is the sum of the value and the previous value of that group multiplied with `min1`. However, for `ID == 'C'` you use a different logic. Why?

Comment: Anyway, a possible solution (which uses the same logic for all ID's and thus gives a somewhat different output): ```library(data.table); DT <- as.data.table(df); DT[, min1 := as.integer(timeslot %in% unique(timeslot+1)), by = ID][, `:=` (sumprev = (variable1 + shift(variable1, fill = 0))*min1, maxprev = max(variable1)*min1, prev_l = .N*min1, prev_l_nonzero = sum(!!variable1)*min1), by = ID][]```.

Comment: In Row 6, it functions over itself, and row 3 because it has the same ID, but in a timeslot below.
In Row 7, it functions over itself, row 9 and row 6. Row 9 because it has the same ID and is in the same timeslot. Row 6 because it has the same ID, and is in the timeslot below. 
Summarized: It takes the all values with the same ID in both the current timeslot and the previous timeslot. If it has no values in the previous timeslot, the value of min1 will be 0, and no functions should be effectuated.